# Spring lifecycle start method not working

Tags: java, spring

I thought I set up a spring bean so that when my web application context gets initialized the start method runs, but it isn't running. When I start my application in debug mode I never hit the breakpoint in the start method. Here's how I have the class set up:

```
@Transactional
@Service
public class ServerStartup implements Lifecycle {

    @Autowired
    private EmpireService es;

    /**
     * sets up the server the first time. Should only be called once
     */
    private boolean setup() {
            [... sets stuff up, saves the empire]
    }

    /**
     * initializes the Empire with its necessary value
     */
    @Override
    public void start() {
        Empire empire = es.getEmpire();
        if (empire == null) {
            //initialize all data as there is no "empire"
            this.setup();
            empire = es.getEmpire();
        }
        Empire.setEmpireGold(empire.getInstanceEmpireGold());

    }

    /**
     * does nothing
     */
    @Override
    public void stop() {
    }

    /**
     * does nothing
     */
    @Override
    public boolean isRunning() {
        return false;
    }       
}
```

The reason I need to do this is that when my program starts up, it needs to check if a map has been built. If it hasn't, it needs to build one. Also, it is essentially setting up a cached value, the Empire's empireGold.

If there's a better, more efficient way to do this than implementing Lifecycle I'd be open to suggestions. Otherwise I just want this to work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is more than one way to instruct Spring to run some initialization logic after a bean has been created. My personal preference is to use the `@PostConstruct` annotation, because it's a standard (defined in the `javax.annotation` package) independent from Spring or any other container.

If you go for this solution and annotate your `start()` method with `@PostConstruct`, don't forget to include `<context:annotation-config/>` in your configuration, otherwise it will be ignored.

See the Spring documentation on this annotation [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-postconstruct-and-predestroy-annotations).
For alternative solutions for the same problem check out the section on ["Customizing the nature of a bean"](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-nature).

Answer (score 1):

Annotate your start method with `@PostConstruct`